# deleted instance IBM-CLOUD

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm new in IBM-cloud, I have not know how to stop ibm-cloud engine (Analytic-engine). Ive receive a mail telling me it'll be suspended (remaining little time. I did not see anywhere to stop it and Ive deleted it(instance). While I tried to create other engine I've got a message telling me I have to wait about 30 days.
I'm using lite account with credit of cognitiveclass (245 days duration)
My Question is: Is it possible to retrieve my instance by contacting support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a service instance is deleted, the underlying cluster is also deleted. All data and metadata, including all logs, on the cluster will be lost after the cluster is deleted.

Also, here are a couple of restrictions using **Lite** plan,

1. Maximum of one tile per IBM Cloud account every 30 days.
2. Maximum of one cluster with up to 3 compute nodes.
3. Free usage limit is 50 node hours. After 50 node hours, the cluster will be disabled. This means, for example, that a cluster with 4 nodes (3 compute node and 1 management node) will be disabled after 12.5 hours. While the cluster is disabled, it cannot be scaled up or customized. 
   A grace period of 24 hours is given to upgrade your user account to a paid account, and to upgrade the service instance to the Standard-Hourly plan. 
   If the service instance is not upgraded, then it will expire and be deleted. 
   Note: You are entitled to one service instance per month. If you delete the service instance or it expires after the free 50 node hours, you will not be able to create a new one until after the month has passed.

Check [this link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsEngine/provisioning.html#provisioning-an-ibm-analytics-engine-service-instance) for other supporting plans

Comment: Thanks I understand.